# Error when reading an XML with Javascript from a different server

Tags: javascript, xml, xmlhttprequest

I am working in an iPhone app in HTML. It needs to retrieve content from an xml stored in a remote server and show its content in a list.

I have already achieved this when the xml file is stored in the same server with this code:

```
    <body>
        <div id="container"> 
            <div id="header">
                <h1><a href="./">BurgerFast</a></h1>
                <p>Menú</p>
                <div>
                    <div id="nav">
                        <ul>
                            <span id="lista"></span>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div id="footer">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="/assets/cl.png">Acerca de</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/assets/cl.png">Ayuda</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
        else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","assets/note.xml",false);
        xmlhttp.send();
        xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;

        var item = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("item")

        var myElems = "";
        for(i = 0 ; i < item.length ; i++){
            myElems = myElems + "<li><a>" + item[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</li></a>";
        }

        document.getElementById("lista").innerHTML =  myElems;


        </script>

    </body>
```

So far, no problem. As the file is hosted in the same server works nicely, but I want to be able to load xml from different servers but mine. When I change the line:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","assets/note.xml",false);
```

and leave itlike this:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://173.236.56.146/~crayonli/xml/note.xml", true);
```

it tells me everytime the **xmldoc is null**, I don't get it, it's the same damn xml.

I just cannot see where's my mistake. Can somebody tell?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy

Comment: As John_doe point out you can call Ajax on different server. But you can use jsonp for this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Comment: Haha, n00b mistake. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use XmlHttp across different domains. Cross domains are not supported.
For achieving it you can use a proxy mechanism or just google xmlhttp cross domain...

This link might help you more [XmlHttp Corss Domain Proxy](http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html)

Comment: That explains why I never find an example with cross domains. I really apreciate your help guys.

Comment: If you are satisfied with some answer, its good that you accept it :)

Comment: you CAN use XHR across domains, but only if the server is returning JSONP.
if the server only returns XML, then you need to make your own proxy.
note: deploying a proxy in php is a lot easier than .NET but mind you, you need to make sure your proxy only talks to 1 server and HTML encodes any GET params etc. to prevent someone exploiting your proxy ..

similar post with a PHP proxy answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11778074/parsing-xml-data-from-a-remote-website